# HighStock x-axis displays numbers when category length is less than max value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, highcharts

In my HighStock Bar graph, x-axis displays numbers, if the category length is less than the max range.
category values are reading from database. Below is my code,

```
$(function () {
                chartOptions = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'column'
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'test',
                        x: -20
                    },

                    xAxis: {
                        categories: color,
                        pointWidth: 28,
                        ordinal: false,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 10,


                        labels: {
                            rotation: -60,
                            align: 'right',
                            useHTML: true,
                            style: {
                                fontSize: '10px',
                                fontFamily: 'proxima-nova,helvetica,arial,sans-seri',
                                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                                paddingLeft: '10px',
                                paddingRight: '10px',
                                paddingTop: '10px',
                                paddingBottom: '10px'


                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'test2'
                        }
                    },

                    yAxis: {

                        allowDecimals: false,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 15,
                        title: {
                            text: 'test3'
                        }



                    },


                    tooltip:
                        {
                            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</td></tr>',
                            footerFormat: '</table>',
                            shared: true,
                            useHTML: true
                        },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            pointPadding: 0.2,
                            borderWidth: 0

                        },

                    },
                    scrollbar: {
                        enabled: true
                    },

                    series: [{
                        name: 'OrderList',
                        data: OrderList
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Historical',
                        data: History
                    }]
                });

            });
```

[image]

if max property not set, the labels comes in double line. How to remove number ticks from x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

In case when you set max param as 10, you print 10 ticks, and if you have less points, all categoreis / ticks are printed until max value will be achieved.

Comment: Can you please explain it more.

Comment: What is unclear? If you have max as 10, you print 10 ticks. If you have 5 categories, 5 are printed, and another ticks are filled by numbers.

Comment: Sorry, i think i have not explained the problem. Requirement is numbers shouldnot get displayed, if category is less than 10.

Comment: So set 5 for max value.